# Configuring PhantomjsDriver to run selenium test cases

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

Am new to this PhantomjsDriver in selenium webdriver.I need to run my selenium scripts in server without GUI. Please can anybody tell me how to achieve this. I need a head's up from the start of how to configure Phantomjs Driver,usage in server and rest.Below is my selenium code which i run through GUI , now i have to run these cases in server without GUI. What modifications i have to do so hat i can achieve the above task.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        login =args[0];
        user = args[1];
        pwd = args[2];
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setOutputDirectory(args[3]);
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {

            CreateMultiRecordTest.class, UpdateMultiRecordTest.class,
            DeleteMultiRecordTest.class

            });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a weeks time i found a solution to configure PhantomJs for my framework.Here's the solution.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
java.io.File f = new java.io.File("");
String path = f.getAbsolutePath()+"\\ghostdriver-master\\src\\main.js";
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY,path);
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
DesiredCapabilities dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
dCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\\phantomjs.exe");
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
```

...